# How to resolve concrete non abstract class instance

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have following issue. I have abstract base type and concrete subtype

```
    public interface IInterface
    {
        void SomeAction()
    }

    public class CClass : IInterface
    {
        public void SomeAction()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

I would like resolve interface dependensies using factory method but sometimes i would like resolve concrete class dependensies without factory method. I mean:

```
    container.RegisterType<IInterface, CClass>(new InjectionFactory(FactoryMethod));
```

My factory method is:

```
    private object FactoryMethod(IUnityContainer arg)
    {
        /* do some specific logic */
        return new CClass();
    }
```

Some times i would like resolve it using factory method:

```
var c1 = container.Resolve<IInterface>();
```

But sometimes I would like resove it without FactoryMethod call

```
var c2 = container.Resolve<CClass>();
```

But FactoryMethod is called every way. Why? What is wrong? I want use factory method for abstract dependensies olnly

Comment: It's been a while since I used unity, isn't it possible to register the concrete type (`CClass`) itself? So the container would know that there is a specific method for `CClass` instead of falling back to the `IInterface` registration?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it is not works i tried add new one type registration for Class. But it still uses inappropriate resolve logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve a concrete class you don't need to register it. Unity will try to create the instance.

To resolve the interface using factory method you need to register only the interface as showed in your answer:

```
container.RegisterType<IInterface>(new InjectionFactory(FactoryMethod));
```

And there is no bad practice here.

BTW, your initial interface registration `container.RegisterType<IInterface, CClass>(new InjectionFactory(FactoryMethod))` gives me `System.InvalidOperationException`. Whatever it is, I don't see any reason to specify the second generic parameter in that case.

Comment: Exception is too strange. Is your CClass not abstract public class?

Comment: yes. It just an empty public class that just implements an empty interface.

Comment: I found out it is related to the version of unity. In the old versions (e.g. 4.0.1) there is no exception.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but i'm no t sure that is the best practies. If I won't write concrete TTo generic parameter type, it works fine.

```
container.RegisterType<IInterface>(new InjectionFactory(FactoryMethod));
```

But it seems it is smell way